# Making a custom mesh in C# managed DirectX

Tags: c#, directx, runtime, managed, mesh

I need to make a DirectX 3D mesh **at run time** using Managed DirectX from C#.  I have not been able to locate any information on how to do this.

1. No, I can't use a 3D modeler program to make my objects.  They must be precisely sized and shaped, and I don't have ANY of the size or shape information until runtime.
2. No, I can't build up the model from existing DirectX mesh capabilities.  (A simple example: DirectX would let you easily model a pencil by using a cone mesh and a cylinder mesh.  Of course, you have to carry around two meshes for your pencil, not just one, and properly position and orient each.  But you can not even make a model of a pencil split in half lengthwise as there is no half cylinder nor half cone mesh provided.)
3. At runtime, I have all of the vertices already computed and know which ones to connect to make the necessary triangles.
4. All I need is a solid color.  I don't need to texture map.

One can get a mesh of a sphere using this DirectX call:
`Mesh sphere = Mesh.Sphere(device, sphereRadius, sphereSlices, sphereStacks);`
This mesh is built at runtime.

What I need to know is how to make a similar function:
`Mesh shape = MakeCustomMesh(device, vertexlist, trianglelist);`
where the two lists could be any suitable container/format.

If anyone can point me to managed DirectX (C#) sample code, even if it just builds a mesh from 3 hardcoded triangles, that would be a great benefit.

Comment: Thanks go out to Reed for the necessary jump start.
Thanks also to Jeff for editing my question.  I can't quite believe I had spelled "managed" wrong twice, in two different ways.  It was obviously late on a Friday.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's some sample code showing how to do this on [MDXInfo](http://www.mdxinfo.com/resources/creatingamesh.php).  This creates a mesh with multiple subsets - if you don't need that, it's even easier.

Basically, you just create the mesh:

```
Mesh mesh = new Mesh(numIndices, numVerticess, MeshFlags.Managed, CustomVertex.PositionColored.Format /* you'll need to set this */ , device);
```

Then, you can grab the mesh vertex buffer and index buffer, and overwrite it, using:

```
IndexBuffer indices = mesh.IndexBuffer;
VertexBuffer vertices = mesh.VertexBuffer;
```

Then, fill in the indices and vertices appropriately.

Comment: I have just created a mesh leaded by your example,but when I exported it by using `ToXFile` method,it failed,I think extra information should be provided to the dynamically created mesh so that it can be saved as x file,could you shed some light on this?Thanks.